# C++ Which library to use when I need to create separate log file for each thread

Tags: c++, logs

I want to write logs into separate files - one log file for each thread. Which C++ library has support for this?

I tried PLOG but it needs static int instanceid as its template parameter while creating multiple loggers. I need it dynamic, I cannot know how many threads my process will have.

I looked at boost but it is not header only (correct me if I am wrong). I do not want to add a lib to my build process.

Any suggestions?